# Раздел математики для изучения алгоритмов

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Какие разделы/раздел математики необходимо изучать для анализа, построения мат. модели, оценки сложности и главное оптимизации и упрощения различных алгоритмов из программирования?

То бишь: мне нужно решить какую-либо задачу, я представил её примерный алгоритм в голове, дальше написал мат. модель своего алгоритма и начал анализировать, упрощать и т.д.

P.S. я полагаю, что Теорию алгоритмов, но я не уверен

Comment: Дискретная математика

Comment: Для того чтобы быть не кодером, а разработчиком систем, необходимо математическое мышление (умение строить абстрактные формализмы), а для этого нужно владеть матаном (понимать, что все гильбертовы пространства изморфны), понимать сходу, что спектр линейного оператора с симметричным ядром лежит в области действительных функций и еще кучу вещей, которые кажется наивным студентам совершенно бесполезными. Чтобы правильно строить алгоритмы и мат.модели нужен университетский базовый курс математики, который укладывается в первые три курса.